# distance between coordinate-wise median and geometric median

Tags: linear-algebra, median, robust-statistics

Let $N \in  \mathbb{N}$ be a constant. Let $B_d(1)$ denote the ball of radius one in $\mathbb{R}^d$. For $i \in \{1,\dots,N\}$, let $a^{(i)}$ be a vector in $B_d(1)$.

Define the geometric median of $a^{(1)}, \dots, a^{(N)}$ as
\begin{equation}
x_\star^{(2)} = \text{argmin}_{x \in \mathbb{R}^d} \sum_{i=1}^{N} \| x - a^{(i)} \|_2.
\end{equation}

Also, define the coordinate-wise median of $a^{(1)}, \dots, a^{(N)}$ as

\begin{equation}
x_\star^{(1)} = \text{argmin}_{x \in \mathbb{R}^d} \sum_{i=1}^{N} \| x - a^{(i)} \|_1.
\end{equation}

My question is how we can characterize the following?
\begin{equation}
\sup_{a^{(1)}\in B_d(1), \dots, a^{(N)} \in B_d(1)} \| x_\star^{(1)} - x_\star^{(2)} \|_2.
\end{equation}

Comment: May I ask what arg means? I know it from complex analysis, but I don't think you mean the same thing.

Comment: the minimizer the objective function.

Comment: A lower bound is obtained for $N=d+1$ the vertices of a regular $d$-simplex at the worst possible alignment ($k$-th vertex with only $k$ nonzero coordinate) so the coordinate-wise median lie in a boundary-$d/2$ simplex, so it should be $\gtrsim\frac12$.

Comment: @user10354138 could you elaborate more?

Comment: We do Gram-Schmidt on the vertices so the first vertex is $(1,0_{d-1})$, the second vertex is $(-1/d,*, 0_{d-2})$, the third vertex is $(-1/d,*,*,0_{d-3})$, etc.  We see the last $d/2$-coordinates of the coord-wise median is $0$ (because that is what the first $d/2$ vertices together imposes).  On the other hand, the first coordinate is the common value of the last $d$ vertices, the second coordinate is the common value of the last $d-1$ vertices etc. That gives the claim the coord-wise median is on a boundary $d/2$-simplex. Then explicit calculation gives $\gtrsim\frac12$ from geo-median $O$.